# How to disable all content inside linear layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-intent, android-widget

Hi I want to disable all content of linear layout by when activity is loaded , when user click on that are , it display alert msg .

After click on activate button , linear layout should be enabled. Whether it is possible or not?

I am able to disable all content inside linear layout using following code:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
for ( int i = 0; i < myLayout.getCount();  i++ ){
    View view = myLayout.getChildAt(i);
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE); // Or whatever you want to do with the view.
 }
```

I want to display alert dialog when user click on disabled area.

please suggest me usable link or sample code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to do as follows:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
for ( int i = 0; i < myLayout.getChildCount();  i++ ){
    View view = myLayout.getChildAt(i);
    view.setEnabled(false); // Or whatever you want to do with the view.
 }
```

Then create an alert Dialog and then

```
myLayout.setOnclickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   onClick(){
     dialog.show();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it, will work instead of getting all view and making disable them

```
myLayout.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score -12):

You can call directly as below, no need to set for each view inside it.

```
myLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // or View.GONE as you needed
```

Comment: The question was to disable the view, not to hide it.