# Is it possible to disable all widgets by disabling their wrapping layout?

Tags: android

[image: img]

I tried to disable the children widgets by disabling the wrapping relativeLayout, but that doesn't work, is there any other way to do that? I think this is necessary because sometimes we don't want to setEnable(xx) on every children widgets. So is it possible for me to do that? or is there some similar way ? thx a lot~

Comment: Assuming you're trying to hide all the children by simply hiding their parent, then call `setVisibility(View.GONE)` or `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` on the parent.  The parent and all it's children will be inaccessible to the user.

Comment: @DeeV, `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` could make them inaccessible, but it's weird if they are invisible, I just want to make them gray and unclickable, is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
for ( int i = 0; i < myLayout.getCount();  i++ ){
   View view = myLayout.getChildAt(i);
   view.setEnabled(false); // Or whatever you want to do with the view.
}
```

I believe you can extend the layout class and implement a new method that does the job. Also, you can check this question: [How to disable all content inside linear layout in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081156/how-to-disable-all-content-inside-linear-layout-in-android)

Comment: if i loop through the children , that could be complicated. if some of the children are enabled, some are disabled, when I set them manually, i should make a record of each widget's isEnabled state, and restore them later in another for loop.. I mean, i wish when i set the parent panel disabled, children could remain their isEnabled states, so that when i enable the parent panel, children widgets are still in their original states

Comment: Yes, you can cache that data and restore it later.